# Can fix only be typed in non-strict evaluated languages?

Tags: haskell, recursion, typechecking, unification, fixpoint-combinators

I write a runtime type checker in and for Javascript and have trouble to type `fix`:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = ...

fix (\rec n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)) 5 -- 120
```

The factorial function passed to `fix` has the simplified type `(Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int`.

When I try to reproduce the expression in Javascript, my type checker fails due to the invalid constraint `Int ~ Int -> Int`.

`fix (const "hallo")` also fails and the type checker complaints that it cannot construct an infinite type (negative occurs check).

With other combinators my unification results are consistent with Haskell's.

Is my unifiction algorithm probably  wrong or can `fix` only be typed in non-strict environments?

[EDIT]

My implementation of `fix` in Javascript is `const fix = f => f(f)`.

Comment: I don't see how typing has anything to do with strictness. This sounds like a bug in your type checker.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Yes, you're right. `(a -> a) -> a` applied to `Num t => (t -> t) -> t -> t` yields the constraint `a ~ t -> t` and hence `Num t => t -> t`. It's a bug.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I have to eta expand `fix` in Javascript and consequently have to type it `fix :: ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> a -> a`. So strictness affects types but in a different way than I thought. This is exciting!

Comment: Another keyword relevant to recursion in strict languages is "value restriction", e.g., http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in the type checker.

It is true though that the naive Haskell definition of `fix` does not terminate in Javascript:

```
> fix = (f) => f(fix(f))
> factf = (f) => (n) => (n === 0) ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)
> fact = fix(factf) // stack overflow
```

You'd have to use an eta-expanded definition in order to the prevent looping evaluation of `fix(f)`:

```
> fix = (f) => (a) => f(fix(f), a)
> factf = (f, a) => (a == 0) ? 1 : a * f(a - 1)
> fact = fix(factf)
> fact(10) // prints 3628800
```

Comment: Thanks. Is `fix = (f) => f(fix(f))` the translation of `fix f = let x = f x in x`? I actually declared `fix = f => f(f)`, which makes `f(f) (n - 1)` necessary as recursive call.

Comment: I guess I got it: `fix = f => f(f)` would be an infinite type. So `fix` must be declared the way you did in order to match `(a -> a) -> a`.

Comment: I indeed used the wrong version of `fix`. When I implement it as your proposed `fix = f => x => f(fix(f)) (x))` and type it explicitly with `((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> a -> a`, it actually works. My type checker is just fine. And as a side effect I finally understood `fix` in Haskell. You got me on the right track. Thanks again!

Comment: @ftor *"I actually declared `fix = f => f(f)`"* I understand the downvotes to your Q now. this ***really*** should have been included in the question! :) (FYI that definition is  **U combinator**, not **Y**).

Comment: @WillNess I didn't realize this connection when I posted the question. Anyway, I don't criticize the downvoters. The difference between `U` and `Y` is now clear to me. It was really helpful to understand their types.

Comment: For an eta-expanded `fix` the type sig `((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> a -> a` is actually not quite accurate. I tried to implement a tail recursive `fact` with an accumulator and it didn't type check. The proper type is `((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b`.

Comment: @ftor that's strange, as `fix` creates chains of compositions, `fix g = g . g . g . g . ...` and `(a->b) . (a->b)` wouldn't typecheck. maybe you ended up doing some  equivalent of a monadic, *extended* composition: `(g <=< g <=< g <=< ...)` so the types aligned as `(a->m a) <=< (a->m a) <=< ...`...

Comment: @WillNess When I check `fix f a = f (fix f) a`'s type in GHCi it is `((t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t` too. Is this the wrong implementation or just a weird GHCi behavior?

Comment: right, I as wrong. `((a -> b) -> (a -> b)) -> (a -> b)` is totally fine, matches the `(t -> t) -> t` type for the chained compositions. thanks!

Comment: my error was that `g :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)`, not `(a -> b)`. so, `(t->t) . (t->t)` typechecks perfectly well, with `t ~ a->b` or any other.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, you tried to implement **U** combinator, which is *not* a fixed-point combinator.

Whereas the fixed-point **Y** combinator `_Y g = g (_Y g)` enables us to write

```
 _Y (\r x -> if x==0 then 1 else x * r (x-1)) 5     -- _Y g => r = _Y g
 -- 120
```

with `_U g = g (g)` we'd have to write

```
 _U (\f x -> if x==0 then 1 else x * f f (x-1)) 5   
                                            -- _U g => f = g, f f == _U g
```

As you've discovered, this **`_U`** has no type in Haskell. On the one hand `g` is a function, `g :: a -> b`; on the other it receives itself as its first argument, so it demands `a ~ a -> b` for *any* types `a` and `b`.

Substituting `a -> b` for `a` in `a -> b` *right away* leads to infinite recursion (cf. "occurs check"), because `(a -> b) -> b` still has that `a` which needs to be replaced with `a -> b`; ad infinitum.

A solution could be to introduce a recursive type, turning `a ~ a -> b` into `R = R -> b` i.e.

```
 newtype U b = U {app :: U b -> b}      -- app :: U b -> U b -> b
```

so we can define

```
 _U :: (U b -> b) -> b
 _U g = g (U g)                         -- g :: U b -> b 
   -- = app (U g) (U g)
   -- = join app (U g)
   -- = (join app . U) g                -- (**)
```

which now has a type; and use it as

```
 _U (\f x -> if x==0 then 1 else x * app f f (x-1)) 5
                                        -- _U g  =>  f = U g, 
 -- 120                                 -- app f f = g (U g) == _U g
```

---

*edit:* And if you want to implement the **Y** combinator as a non-recursive definition, then

```
 _U (\f x -> if x==0 then 1 else x * (app f f) (x-1))
=                                    -------.-               -- abstraction
 _U (\f -> (\r x -> if x==0 then 1 else x * r (x-1)) (app f f))
=          -------.---------------------------------         -- abstraction
 (\g -> _U (\f -> g (app f f))) (\r x -> if x==0 then 1 else x * r (x-1))
=                                                            --  r = app f f 
 _Yn                            (\r x -> if x==0 then 1 else x * r (x-1))
```

so

```
 _Yn :: (b -> b) -> b
 _Yn g = _U (\f -> g (app f f))         -- Y, non-recursively
```

does the job:

```
 _Yn (\r x -> if x==0 then 1 else x * r (x-1)) 5
 -- 120
```

---

(*later update:*) Or, point-freer,

```
 _Yn g = _U (\f -> g (app f f))
       = _U (\f -> g (join app f))
       = _U (\f -> (g . join app) f)
       = _U (g . join app)
       = _U ( (. join app) g )
```

Thus

```
 _Yn :: (b -> b) -> b
 _Yn = _U . (. join app)                -- and, using (**)
     = join app . U . (. join app)
```

Comment: I am curious if this newtype along with `U`'s implementation in Javascript satisfies my type checker. I use Scott to encode ADTs, hence my type will be less concise. Thank you Will!